# StateMachineBehaviour.OnStateExit is called before StateMachineBehaviour.OnStateEntered is called

Tags: unity, state

When I start my game I get null-references in my OnStateExit of objects that are initialized in the OnStateEntered. After this it goes smooth, so it only occurs at startup before any conditions for statechanges are met.

How come? My understanding is that OnStateExit is always preceded by OnStateEntered.

My StateBehaviour

```
public class DuckStateBehaviour : BaseStateBehaviour {

    override public void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex) 
    {
        base.OnStateEnter(animator, stateInfo, layerIndex);
        mMovement.BeginDuck();
    }

    public override void OnStateExit(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        if (mMovement != null) mMovement.EndDuck();
        base.OnStateExit(animator, stateInfo, layerIndex);
    }
}

public class BaseStateBehaviour : StateMachineBehaviour {

    protected Transform mTransform = null;
    protected Rigidbody2D mRigidBody = null;
    protected IMovement mMovement = null;

    public override void OnStateEnter(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
    {
        mTransform = animator.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
        mRigidBody = animator.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        mMovement = animator.gameObject.GetComponent<IMovement>();

        Debug.Assert(mTransform != null);
        Debug.Assert(mRigidBody != null);
        Debug.Assert(mMovement != null);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's of any help (I'm not familiar with Unity), but the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.html) does not seem to say _" that OnStateExit is always preceded by OnStateEntered."_ It says that `OnStateEnter`_"- Called on the first Update frame when a statemachine evaluate this state."_ and `OnStateExit` _"- Called on the last update frame when a statemachine evaluate this state."_ Maybe the 'default' state is unloaded but not explicitly loaded. And maybe it's a bug.

Comment: That would suggest that their is a last update frame when the statemachine evaluates this state but no first update frame. This smells very weird.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have a transition, one state can start and the other can still be executing (updating): So yes, they can happen in the "wrong" way.